# Yii 1.1 and passing by reference

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to create a tree of categories on Yii 1.1.

I wrote this code:

```
$tree=array();
$results=Category::model()->findAll();

foreach ($results as &$result)
{
    if(empty($result->parent_id))
    {
        $tree[$result->parent_id]=&$result->name;
    }
    else
    {
        $results[$result->parent_id]['childs'][$result->id]=&$result->name;
    }
}

return $tree;
```

I'm getting I getting this error

```
Indirect modification of overloaded property Category::$name has no effect
```

Why? How am I can it fix?

Thank you!

Comment: why do you want to store reference? Not required to store reference.

Comment: Can I see an example? With using an one query to database

Comment: just remove `&` in `$results as &$result` and `$tree[$result->parent_id]=&$result->name;` and `$results[$result->parent_id]['childs'][$result->id]=&$result->name;`

Answer (score 0):

To give you an answer why this occurs (and it's not a specific Yii issue but more PHP in general): 
`$result->name` is not an actual variable, but the result of a function call. Internally it `calls $result->__get('name')`

PHP is just trying to warn you that it thinks your doing something strange.
The solution is to assign the result to a variable and use that instead.
Annoying, I know.

That being said: Why are you trying to use references anyway?